# Assigning a BOOL from a MySQL result

Tags: mysql, ruby, boolean, prepared-statement, exists

I'm hacking together my first ruby script to read and write to/from mysql.

I want to know if a certain record exists. I have tried:

```
sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserTrucks WHERE User = ? AND Truck = ?)"
pst = con.prepare(sql)
does_exist = pst.execute(user_id, truck_id)
```

but when I print the class of should_alert, it is a MySQL::STMT rather than a True or False class, or even a 0/1.

What am I missing here? Is a prepared statement even the right thing to use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use count

```
sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Exist FROM UserTrucks WHERE User = ? AND Truck = ?"
```

or

```
sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserTrucks WHERE User = ? AND Truck = ?) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Exist"
```

Comment: `EXISTS` is much more optimized. In your `COUNT(*)` solution, you actually need to **count all rows**. Whereas in an `EXISTS` query, MySQL stops looking once it finds a single row.

Comment: I see how this would explicitly return me a 1 or 0 but would like to see a more standard way to do this (on top of the performance impact @ShlomiNoach mentions).

Comment: It's just a condition you can replace it with any expression. Since you are using WHERE clause, few rows are returned, so performance issue is minimal

Answer (score 1):

```
sql = "SELECT IF( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserTrucks WHERE User = ? AND Truck = ?), 1, 0)"
```